# Making HTML images, to glow in CSS as transitions

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I've made a simple login system. But I don't know how to make it as transitions.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xcefgg9g/

HTML

```
    <body>

   <!-- Header
   ================================================== -->
   <header id="home">
      <div class="row banner">
         <div class="banner-text">
         <div class="stop">
        <div class="logo"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/R6bUhGI.png" width="500" height="500" ></img></div>
              <div class="text">Alege ce ești.</div>
<div class="jucator"><a href="https://google.com"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SMHDIim.png"> </a>
        <a href="https://google.com">  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PAGOmxn.png"></a></div>


         </div>
      </div>



   </header> <!-- Header End -->
```

CSS

```
    body { background: #0f0f0f; }
header {
   position: relative;
   height: 800px;
   min-height: 500px;
   width: 100%;
   background: #161415 url(http://i.imgur.com/GOX7opa.gif)  top center;
   background-size: cover !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}

header:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 100%;
}
header .banner {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 85%;
   padding-bottom: 30px;s
   text-align: center;
}

header .banner-text { width: 100%; }
header .banner-text h1 {
   font: 90px/1.1em 'opensans-bold', sans-serif;
   color: #fff;
   letter-spacing: -2px;
   margin: 0 auto 18px auto;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.jucator
{
padding-top:0px;
padding-left:200px;
}

.logo
{padding-left:181px;
padding-bottom:25px;
}

.text{
    padding-bottom:50px;
    padding-left:200px;
    font-size: 200%;

}
```

Live:  http://vestigedayz.com/nerve/

I want to make Jucator  and Observator  images as transitions (When cursor goes on Jucator, it will show a light under image,  and when goes to Observator it will show another color)

And when I press on it, I want to bring login section as a transition (slowly)

How can I make this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a basic layout for you.

For the buttons, I just added a box-shadow transition on hover.

For the login page I just made it transition from top when you click on any of the buttons (you can play around with it, or have your own transition).

Pretty straightforward, let me know if you have questions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // first login page
  $(".landing-page-buttons .first-login").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".login-page.first").toggleClass("open");
  });
  
  $(".first .close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".login-page.first").toggleClass("open");
  });
  
  // second login page
  $(".landing-page-buttons .second-login").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".login-page.second").toggleClass("open");
  });
  
  $(".second .close").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".login-page.second").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;  
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px white
}

.main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.landing-page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
  z-index: 0;
}

.landing-page-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.landing-page-buttons ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;  
}

.landing-page-buttons ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;  
}

.login-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 5;
}

.login-page.open {
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="landing-page">
    <div class="landing-page-buttons">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="first-login" href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a class="second-login" href="#">Also Login</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="login-page first">
    <h3>First Login Page</h3>
    <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    <ul class="login-form">
      <li>Username: <input type="text"></li>  
      <li>Password: <input type="text"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="login-page second">
    <h3>Second Login Page</h3>
    <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    <ul class="login-form">
      <li>Username: <input type="text"></li>  
      <li>Password: <input type="text"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it shows this area when I acces the page?  http://i.imgur.com/s5cWglD.png

Comment: @EminEryilmaz you mean the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Yes @zsawaf  it won't show my background, it shows that grey background instead.

Comment: @EminEryilmaz that's because I didn't use your code. I scrapped my own code real quick to give you an idea how you could implement something like this on your own.

Comment: got it, thanks. How can I apply size on buttons? I want make them to look increased,

Comment: @EminEryilmaz 1- increase font size on "a" tags. 2- increase padding on "a" tags. You can target those specific landing page "a" tags in your css.

Comment: Thank you @zsawaf  everything works perfect ! last question, can I make two separate login forms? At Jucator login I want to type different text, and at Observator I want to type another text.

Comment: @EminEryilmaz Yep! You certainly can. All you need is to create another div, exactly like the login-page div, just call it something else, and apply the same javascript + css to it.

Comment: i tried to make it again, but it won't show. Can you  help me? Here's the demo. https://jsfiddle.net/b6aqhdv0/

Comment: @EminEryilmaz I updated my snippet to reflect a second login page. You can change class names to have a better semantic meaning

Answer (score 0):

```css
  body { background: #0f0f0f; }
header {
   position: relative;
   height: 800px;
   min-height: 500px;
   width: 100%;
   background: #161415 url(http://i.imgur.com/GOX7opa.gif)  top center;
   background-size: cover !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}

header:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 100%;
}
header .banner {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 85%;
   padding-bottom: 30px;s
   text-align: center;
}

header .banner-text { width: 100%; }
header .banner-text h1 {
   font: 90px/1.1em 'opensans-bold', sans-serif;
   color: #fff;
   letter-spacing: -2px;
   margin: 0 auto 18px auto;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.jucator
{
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px;
-webkit-transition: background 2s;
    transition: background 2s;
}

.jucator:hover{
  background: blue;
}

.observator{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: background 2s;
    transition: background 2s;
}

.observator:hover{
  background: green;
}

.logo
{padding-left:181px;
padding-bottom:25px;
}

.text{
    padding-bottom:50px;
    padding-left:200px;
    font-size: 200%;
    
}
```

```html
</body>

</html>


<body>

   <!-- Header
   ================================================== -->
   <header id="home">
      <div class="row banner">
         <div class="banner-text">
         <div class="stop">
        <div class="logo"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/R6bUhGI.png" width="500" height="500" ></img></div>
              <div class="text">Alege ce ești.</div>
          <center>
            <div class="jucator"><a href="https://google.com"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SMHDIim.png"> </a></div>
        <div class="observator">
        <a href="https://google.com">  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PAGOmxn.png"></a>
        </div>
       
          </center>
          
     
        


         </div>
      </div>



   </header> <!-- Header End -->
```

You could try something like this using css transitions with :hover on each button. This would be move suitable if you don't want to use jquery.

Comment: Thank you ! But someone made something convenable !

Comment: yes, it was helpful ! :) Someone came with better graphics.

Comment: Great glad I could help!